# Can't get where is the memory leak in the function

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, nib, macos-carbon

I am having a problem in identifying a memory leak. I tried Instruments and it says that there is memory leak every time I call the function described below.

```
CFStringRef getStringFromLocalizedNIB(int cmdId)
{
    IBNibRef        nibRef;
    WindowRef       wind=NULL;
    CFStringRef     alertString;

    CreateNibReference(CFSTR("main"), &nibRef);
    CreateWindowFromNib(nibRef, CFSTR("Localized Strings"), &wind);
    DisposeNibReference(nibRef);

    ControlID   alertID = {'strn',cmdId};
    ControlRef  alertRef;
    GetControlByID(wind, &alertID,&alertRef);
    GetControlData(alertRef, kControlNoPart, kControlStaticTextCFStringTag, sizeof(CFStringRef), &alertString, NULL);
    return alertString;
}
```

Every time I call the function, I release the returned object.

```
CFStringRef lstr;
lstr = getStringFromLocalizedNIB(20);
//Use lstr;
CFRelease(lstr);
```

So can anybody please explain where the leak is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you aren't showing the window created using CreateWindowFromNib().   I would expect the window to have the Carbon equivalent of release-on-close, and the CreateWindowFromNib() to be balanced by a ShowWindow().  I haven't done Carbon in 9 years though, so I'm not sure.

Try calling DisposeWindow() on wind to balance the create:

```
    ...
    DisposeWindow(wind);
    return alertString;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @iccir for the reply. The problem is that I have 2 top level objects in my nib file. Do I have to release them as well? If so, how can I release them if I am not creating WindowRef for the other window.

Comment: Are leaks showing up still after the DisposeWindow() call?  In Cocoa, you have to release all top level objects.  In this case, I'm not sure - you have a valid point, as you aren't creating the others.

Comment: Yes, the leaks were still showing after DisposeWindow(). Now instead of creating a reference to the nib everytime I call this function, I am only creating the reference once and using that reference every time. So the leaks are gone :). Anyway, thanks for replying :)